# Is it true that a distributive lattice with finite length is finite

Tags: lattice-orders

I am trying to show that a distributive lattice of finite length is itself finite.

Clearly if a lattice is finite it is of finite length. How can I show the other implication?

Note that we also have if $L$ is a distributive lattice with finite length, there are finitely many join-irreducible elements. I think we must use this fact somehow.

Comment: In ZFC, I think that any counterexample would have to have an infinite antichain, and then distributivity would let you rotate it into an infinite chain, a contradiction. I'm not sure if this works, but it's probably worth trying if you don't have a better idea.

Comment: Of course an infinite partially ordered set with no infinite chain must have an infinite antichain (in the classical sense, i.e., set of pairwise imcomparable elements). How does distributivity "let you rotate it into an infinite chain"?

Comment: I am also not seeing how this is done.

Comment: @bof I think we must use that there are only finitely many join-irreducible elements but I am not sure how.

Comment: @bof if a1, a2,.. is an infinite antichain, then a1, a1.a2, a1.a2.a3, etc,  where . is inf (or sup) of two elements, is an infinite chain.

Comment: @WilliamElliot In the lattice of subsets of $\omega,$ if $a_1,a_2,a_3,\dots$ is an infinite sequence of pairwise disjoint sets, then $a_1,a_2,a_3,\dots$ is an infinite antichain, but $a_1,a_1\cap a_2,a_1\cap a_2\cap a_3,\dots$ is not an infinite chain.

Answer (score 2):

For any $x$ in a distributive lattice, the upper set of $\{x\}$, that is, $\uparrow x$, is a distributive sublattice.
A distributive lattice of finite length has a bottom $0$, and the set of covers of $0$, the join-irreducible elements, is finite.
Let $L(n)$ be:  every distributive lattice of length $\leq n$, is finite.

Clearly $L(0)$ and $L(1)$.
Now assume $L(n)$ and let $L$ be a distributive lattice of length $n + 1$.
Let $K = \{ a_1, \ldots, a_k \}$ be the set of bottom covers.
$L$ is the union of $\{0\}$ and $\uparrow a_1, \ldots, \uparrow a_k$.
Each $\uparrow a_j$ is a distributive lattice of length $\leq n$, thus finite.
Whereupon $L$, a finite union of finite sets, is finite.

Thence $L(n+1)$ and therefore every distributive lattice of finite length can be induced to be finite.

Easy exercise.  Show distributive is necessary with
an example of an infinite lattice with finite length.

Comment: Notice however that the join-irreducible elements are not necessarily only the ones that cover the bottom element (that seems to be suggested in the second line); when that happens, in the finite case, the lattice is actually boolean.